# C++: Bilateral class conversion

Tags: c++

Let's say, I have two simple classes: `integer` with just one `int` variable in it, and `real` with `double`. I'm already done so that

`integer a=2016;
int b=a;`

`real a=20.16;
double b=a;`

working perfectly. Now I have to do the conversion between them, like so:

`integer foo; real bar;
foo=bar;
bar=foo;`

Or at least with similar syntax. I know that there will be loss of some data when converting double to int, I'll deal with it. So how can I do that? What and where should I #include and what the methods/operator overloads to write? My project is divided into files `main.cpp`, `integer.h`, `integer.cpp`, `real.h`, `real.cpp`. Thanks.

EDIT: The classes looks like:

```
//integer.h
class integer
{
    private:
        int a;
    public:
        integer();
        integer(int number);
        operator int() const;
};
//integer.cpp
#include "integer.h"

integer::integer(){
    a=0;
}
integer::integer(int number){
    a=number;
}
integer::operator int() const{
    return a;
}
//real.h
class real {
    private:
        double a;
    public:
        real();
        real(double number);
        operator double() const;
};
//real.cpp
#include "real.h"

real::real(){
    a=0;
}
real::real(double number){
    a=number;
}
real::operator double() const{
    return a;
}
```

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator

Comment: you'll need to show us minimal versions of these classes to get a good answer.

Comment: @erip Doesn't inheritance, in this case, have the [circle-ellipse problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle-ellipse_problem)?

Comment: inheritance would be the wrong solution for two classes with dissimilar interfaces. real numbers and integers are absolutely dissimilar.

Comment: Edited, inserted the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically have two solutions to your problem:

The first is to write [conversion operators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator) that can convert a `real` object to an `integer` object, and vice versa.

The other solution is to implement custom constructors and assignment operators to take the other class.

Comment: I've tried to do like in first example of "Explanation", got "Incomplete type used in nested name specifier". How to do the second variant?

Comment: @1valdis Only put the conversion operator function ***declarations*** in the class. Then ***define*** (i.e. implement) the function after both classes are fully defined.

Comment: I did declare functions in headers, defined in their .cpp's. Where else should I do that?

Comment: @1valdis You do remember to add forward declarations of the classes, not including the header files into each other and thereby creating a circular dependency? See e.g. [this simple example on how it could be done](http://ideone.com/JnL92S).

Comment: Yes, I write class real; before class integer{...} and so on.